# Printing a portion of a page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing

I am printing a page by the printer, using JS function `print(window.print())`. But, it prints the whole page, including the `"Print" button`, which looks odd. I want to print the page without that button. May be printing the `page-wrapper div` would be good. What should I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Here a bunch of way on printing a page. 
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-print-page-options/
Hope it helps :)

Comment: @daR: The question isn't tagged with jQuery, though.

Comment: Im just trying to help :) sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your page's "printed" display, by using a print-specific stylesheet, imported like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

In that stylesheet, you could remove elements you don't want to show in on the printed page:

```
.printButton{
    display: none;
}
```

Or, if you're not concerned about IE 8 compatibility, something like this might work:

```
:not(.page-wrapper div){
    display:none;
}
```

For more information, "A List Apart" has a [nice tutorial on the subject](http://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint)